# How to access data attribute value in jquery (cash-dom)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I use webpack and the data-cash. I have a link with data attribute that I want to access. 
HTML:

```
<a class="myBtn" data-article="some value">
   <div>some text here</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
  $('.myBtn').on('click', (e) => {
    const articleData = $(e.currentTarget);
    console.log(articleData);

    modal.style.display = 'block';
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

The code above returns

```
Cash [a.myBtn]
```

How can I access the value of data attribute (article)?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/data  The API is your friend

Answer (score 1):

<s>Try with `$(this).data('article')` inside your event listener. jQuery has a **[.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** function for  those purposes.</s>

**EDIT:** Attached a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zn6q9mt/).

For cash-dom jQuery you should use [**.attr()**](https://github.com/kenwheeler/cash#fnattr-) instead of `.data()`. According to their docs you can get your `data-article` attribute by doing `$(element).attr('data-article')`.

Comment: This returns undifined

Comment: I know that I can access it by using the code above $(this).data('article') but I use webpack and cash-dom and it doesn't work. The code that I have above at least returns some value but don't know how to access the data in it.

Comment: Have you tried with `.attr('data-article')`? I haven't noticed it's a cash-dom jQuery. Sorry.

Comment: attr('data-article') is works fine but I need to access it like this: $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-article')

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer, where `$(element)` stands for your `$(e.currentTarget)`. Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

My solution looks like this:

```
  $('.myBtn').on('click', (e) => {        
    const articleData = $(e.currentTarget);
    articleData.attr('data-article')
    console.log(articleData.attr('data-article'));           
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```